# Angular 2 Remove Hash (#) from the URL

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to remove the # sign from the url in Angular 2 but I couldn't find any good explanation about how to remove it without generate any problem.

I remember on AngularJS 1 it was easier adding `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

Also I would appreciate if you can tell me if this is a good practice (removing #) or could affect the SEO for the application (or improve it).

PS: I am using Angular 2 with typescript

Answer (score 98, accepted):

As @Volodymyr Bilyachat pointed out, `PathLocationStrategy` is a default [location strategy](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles) in Angular2, and if the `#` is present in the url, it must have been that's overridden somewhere.

Beside the module providers, check your module imports, it can also be overridden by providing the `{ useHash: true }` as the second argument of the `RouterModule.forRoot`:

```
imports: [
    ...
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })  // remove second argument
]
```

Also note that when using `PathLocationStrategy` you need to configure your web server to serve `index.html` (app's entry point) for all requested locations.

Here are configuration examples for some of the popular web servers: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback-configuration-examples

Comment: Folks, In ng build --prod this solution is not working, gives 404 error..any clue?

Comment: This solves the problem of # removal but when we refresh the page or h5 this doen't work.

Comment: @HydTechie, JinnaBalu, When using PathLocationStrategy (HTML5 routing), you need to configure your webserver to serve index.html file (app's entry point) for all requested urls.

Comment: HI Seid, can you please let me know what and how to configure the web-server, when using the PathLocationStrategy.

Comment: @SuchetaShrivastava The Angular docs added a section of examples for web server configurations for PathLocationStrategy implementations: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback-configuration-examples

Comment: I have one more file(callback.html) except index.html and I am using PathLocationStrategy. But I am not able to hit that callback.html file. what can be the issue ?

Comment: to remove the hash I had to use `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: false})` (Angular 8)

Answer (score 41):

In angular there is [location strategy](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/LocationStrategy-class.html)

Look into app.module.ts where app is bootstrapped there you have

```
@NgModule({
.......
  providers: [
....
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
....
]
});
```

And remove this part since PathLocationStrategy is [default strategy](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles)

Comment: its working  for ng serve, but not for ng build --prod, any clue? thanks!

Comment: The error is 404, the link without # is showing as 404 in IIS.. I know there were some setting required to setup in iis to redirect, but i was looking without that, if possible. appreciate!

Comment: @HydTechie no its not. Look for SPApageFallback package

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat,  If I use `HashLocationStrategy `,  the `navigate` does not work in both developement and production any Idea ?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat this tric  is not working on production... but works in local

Comment: this will still show the "#" in the url

Answer (score 24):

Above answers have the correct explanation about removing the Hash from the URL, but when you change `LocationStrategy` your back-end will be affected because the back-end doesn't understand all of your `Angular 2` Routes. Here are the steps to remove hash with the back-end support.

1) Change Angular to use PathLocationStrategy

```
@NgModule({
  .....
  providers: [
    // Below line is optional as default LocationStrategy is PathLocationStrategy
    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy} 
  ]
})
```

2) Change the base Href in index.html, Angular2 will handle all routes post base Href

```
<base href="/app-context/">
```

For example

```
<base href="/app/">
```

3) At the backend server, we must render the index.html file for any request coming with below pattern

```
"/app/**" - Render index.html for any request coming with "/app/**" pattern
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My App</title>
    <base href="/app/">
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you give a brief explanation about "/app-context/".