# angular 2 routing, useHash strips route parameters

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular2-routing

I am working on a simple angular 2 application and routing does not seem to be working for me.

When I am trying to do routing for my application with a url like myapp.com/15/hello, the url parameters are preserved with non hash routing with the code like this

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
    { path: '**', component: MyComponent },
])
```

However when I move to useHash routing, if i try to do the same request myapp.com/15/hello, the parameters extra parameters are stripped from the url and becomes like this : 
myapp.com/#/

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
    { path: '**', component: MyComponent},
],
    {
        useHash: true,
    })
```

Is there any way to usehash navigation without it stripping the extra parameters from the url?

Thank you

Comment: no there is not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Remove Hash (#) from the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41687562/angular-2-remove-hash-from-the-url)

Answer (score 0):

The path '**' is used for undefined routes. You should instead use '' to route to myComponent:

```
{
    path     : '',
    component: myComponent
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. I have tried this and it still strips the url from myapp.com/15/hello to myapp.com/#/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
My solution was to remove the

```
<base href="/">
```

from the header.
This works only if you use the "useHash" Routing strategy.
I hope this solves your problem.