# Website is not loading on server while refresh it from browser in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, browser-refresh

I am unable to reload my website when refresh from browser in angular 2

1. I don't want hash '#' symbol in url thus remove it from routing use hash
2. redirect to same page from app.component from getting active url

Not Found
The requested document was not found on this server.
Web Server at someserver.com

Comment: Can you provide more details? Where you publish your website?

Comment: [RTFM](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration) my friend

Comment: If it is Apache server, then you need to configure `.htaccess` accordingly.

Comment: Are you using `node` as a server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2: 404 error occur when I refresh through the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284988/angular-2-404-error-occur-when-i-refresh-through-the-browser)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to config on the server that every route will be responses with the `index.html`.

Comment: I am using angular 2 routing with app_initializer which is fetching data from DB for dynamic route collection

Answer (score 0):

1) For remove, hash please [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41687900/8612835)

2) For reloading issue, You have two options.

```
I) Use .htaccess and set the path in that 
II) Allow you dist folder from node.
```

**Smple .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /{{project folder name}}/ [NC,L]
```