# How to fix the classic anchor method (id-href) in Angular?

Tags: angular, hash, routes, hashref

On the homepage component I use scrolling in order to show the different divs of the page. The div looks loke this:

```
<div id="paragraph1">Paragraph1</div>
<div id="paragraph2">Paragraph2</div>
<div id="paragraph3">Paragraph3</div>
```

On the same page I have a menu component which links the menu buttons to the corresponding div:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#paragraph1">Paragraph1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#paragraph2">Paragraph2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#paragraph3">Paragraph3</a></li>
</ul>
```

It seems to work fine: clicking on a menu button leads me to the corresponding div start in the page but it simulaneously throws a console error:

```
ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'paragraph1'
```

I think it is related to the router.ts config which does not contain the hrefs of the divs:

```
export const routes: Array<Route> = [
{ path: '/home', component: HomeComponent}];
```

Any ideas how I can fix the error? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your Angular code is using the `HashLocationStrategy`, which is interfering with the natural behaviour of the browser to follow the hash segment and move to the appropriate element in the viewport.

One way is to use the [`PathLocationStrategy`](https://angular.io/api/common/PathLocationStrategy) instead. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41687585/2019247) for an example to configure your app this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below

```
<div #paragraph1>Paragraph1</div>
<div #paragraph2>Paragraph2</div>
<div #paragraph3>Paragraph3</div>

<ul>
   <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="scroll(paragraph1)">Paragraph1</a></li>
   <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="scroll(paragraph2)">Paragraph2</a></li>
   <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="scroll(paragraph2)">Paragraph3</a></li>
</ul>

  scroll(el: HTMLElement) {
    el.scrollIntoView();
  }
```