# Remove HashTag from route path in Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Routing Module has common hashtag representation `{ useHash: true }`, dont have for specific path.

```
  { path: 'documentDelivered', component: DocumentDeliveredComponent },
  { path: 'health', component: MonitoringComponent },

  @NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
```

http://localhost:4200/#/documentDelivered

> I need to remove hashtag(#) only for below "health" path.

http://localhost:4200/#/health

Comment: Can you tell me if there is some other module there you are assigning (#) to some path ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 Remove Hash (#) from the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41687562/angular-2-remove-hash-from-the-url)

Comment: I don't think what you are doing is possible. It is entirely dependent on the whole Angular Router strategy chosen and cannot be changed in-app.

Comment: Angular router work with hash or without hash, not with both.
https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles

Comment: @AlexBeugnet this answer for all path, not to specific path

Comment: no you can't ,  either use it in all or you don't . you will have to choose a Router strategy

Comment: @SamiHK, here using single routing-module, dont have another routing module.   `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],` if we change to false, it affect all the path. i only require for partiular path.

Comment: @Mano You would need use REGEX for these routes and if REGEX-PATTERN matches you would have to replace the # by window.location.replace()

Comment: To me it makes no sense to have two routing path strategies on the same app. I believe you should look into this as I've never seen any other project wanting to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps I implemented and it's working fine

1. Remove `useHash: true` from router modules, By default its false.
   [image]
2. Add `/` slash to base href in the index page

[image]

Now it working fine in the dev environment.

For prod, we need to add rules in (.htaccess) file.

Fix for restriction of redirection to siblings and children paths in the router.
Basically the issue arises in prod not in dev.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # Redirection of requests to index.html
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Ref: https://julianpoemp.github.io/ngx-htaccess-generator/#/generator

cheers :)