# Angular 8: Loading module from "url" was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, angular7, angular8

I have created the application in Angular 8 and Node 12.

After creating angular 8 build I am facing this problem while opening a new tab or page reload I have searched all around the internet did not found any solution.

Firefox console:
[image: Error]

Google Chrome console:
[image]

TSCONFIG:

[image]

Other than that everything works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you running the site? Are you using `ng serve`? This sort of issue is usually not with the project itself, but with the hosting environment. Can you add an image of the command line you serve the site from please?

Comment: I have created build and serving it with node js.

Comment: commnd I have used: ng build baseHref=./ --prod

Comment: Try running it with `ng serve` and see what happens.

Comment: @HockeyJ It works pretty much smooth as expected

Answer (score 1):

I was roaming around the internet I found the answer here:

> [Angular 2 Remove Hash (#) from the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41687562/angular-2-remove-hash-from-the-url)

So basically there was a `#` URL problem which I come across and by setting up `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })` I am able to successfully run the application.

Thank you guys for helping me